# WebPICMD Retired

Tags: azure-service-fabric, web-platform-installer

Reading this article on WebPI from August, 2022, I would think WebPI was active, but now I get from the command line that it's retired.

Are there any alternatives to this?

I was trying to install Service Fabric:

```
PS C:\Users\caec> C:\"Program Files"\"Microsoft SDKs"\Azure\".NET SDK"\v2.9\bin\plugins\WebDeploy\WebpiCmd.exe /List /ListOption:All

The software that you obtain using the Web Platform Installer Command Line Tool is licensed to you by its owner.  Microsoft grants you no rights for third party software.
Successfully loaded primary feed: https://aka.ms/webpifeed51

Current language of installers is English
There are no products available for Previously Installed Products

--Available Products
ID                   Title
----------------------------------------
WebPIRetired         The Web Platform Installer is now officially retired
There are no products available for Applications
```

Are there any other ways to install Service Fabric with some kind of package manager?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and installed the service fabric successfully .**

Yes, the Web Platform Installer (WebPI) is retired on September 1, 2022 & no longer supported and has been removed. Using tools like **`PowerShell`**, **`NuGet`**, and **`Chocolatey`**, Microsoft has shifted to a more current package method.

You can install the service fabric cluster using PowerShell Gallery to download the Service Fabric SDK and related modules.

- Open Powershell command prompt and run as administrator.

**Command:**

```
Install-Module -Name Az.ServiceFabric -RequiredVersion 3.1.0
```

**Console:**
[image]

Once its installation done, you can import the **`Service Fabric modules`** by running the following command:

**Command:**

```
 Import-module -Name Az.ServiceFabric
```

Once imported you can use the **`get-module`** command to verify it is installed.

[image]

Another approach is **`Chocolatey package manager`** same as PowerShell run as administrator.

**Command:**

```
choco install service-fabric
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Chocolatey Software | Service Fabric 9.1.1390](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/service-fabric#install)